# Is there meaning to multiplying constant of integration by a constant?

Tags: integration

A specific example of what I am asking about:

$$\frac{4}{x^2}\int x^3dx =\frac{4}{x^2}\cdot \left(\frac{x^4}4 +C \right)=x^4+(4C)or(C)$$

would saying $4C$ differ from $C$ only?

Would either of them be considered wrong mathematically?

Comment: I'm not sure that you got your integral right, but no, it doesn't matter. $4C_1$ can just be equal to $C_2$. However, it does change if you have a double integral, where you may have $Cx$.

Comment: $\int \frac4{x^2} dx = -\frac4x + c=-\frac4x + 123912d$ etc. But $C$ and $4C$ are different. So if you end up manipulating the end result, it does matter that you 'fix' this constant term once and for all. (And indeed above, you can find a relation between these constants $d$ and $c$, i.e. $c=123912d$.)

Answer (score 1):

By abuse of notation, the actually meaning of
$$
\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x = g(x)+C
$$ 
is
$$
\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \{g(x)+C : C \in K\}
$$ 
where $K$ is the field you are considering with (e.g. $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$).

So you can immediately see what happens.

Comment: I personally think $$\int f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \in \{ g(x)+C : C\in K \}$$ is better since the integral is itself a function, not a set of functions.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor You are right. I have not considered about "$\in$".

Comment: Happy to help, my friend $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

The only time it would prove a problem later would be if there is a *specific* $C$ for which you have to solve, as in definite integration.

If the indefinite antiderivative is your ‘final answer,’ you should stick to just $C$, partly because of convention, and also because you wouldn’t want to imply that $C$ is a specific number.

Other than that, it doesn’t really matter.